# Is there a way to set a static IP's last 3 digits only in linux?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I need to set up several ubuntu systems that will end up being plugged into routers with varying IP addresses. For example, 192.168.1.x or 192.168.0.x, etc. Is there a way of assigning a static IP address based on any router's address? Lets say, that I want the final digits (x) to be 77, regardless of the router address. If the box is on a 192.168.0.x router, it would set its static IP as 192.168.0.77. If the box is on a 192.168.1.x router, it would set its static IP as 192.168.1.77. And so on... Is there a way to do this in either the interfaces file or wpa_supplicant?

Comment: why is the last octet (the fourth number) significant at all ? dns updated from dhcp is your friend. You'll need to put a static reservation on each router for that device though.

Comment: That would totally break DHCP.  The whole address needs to be unique on a LAN, not part of it.  If it were even possible, clashes would be common.  However, you can set some routers to always give the same IP to specific MAC addresses which could achieve something close to what you're asking.

Comment: it'd still be unique because each rotuer is in a different subnet and the reservation third octet would differ based on dhcp view per subnet. It's a bad idea though, it's over complicated, and puts a weird significance onto the value of fourth octet, which seems illogical.

Comment: @Sirex, he wants the host part of the address to be static and the network part to be dynamic.  It won't be unique unless he knows exactly which clients are connecting with what IP's.  Reservations based on the client MAC are the only option.

Comment: i think we've a misunderstanding because we're saying the same thing in different ways. You need a reservation in each subnet for the same mac, yes. It should be possible to do that with dhcp via per-subnet dhcp scopes, but it's certainly a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script to check the current assigned IP and then change it so that it ends with 100.

This only works if you have DHCP running in the network. If not, you need some extra steps to check the router IP.

```
#!/bin/bash

#set interface
interface="eth0"

#read current IP address on interface
current_ip=`ifconfig $interface 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $2}'|sed 's/addr://'`
IP=`cut -f1,2,3 -d"." <<< $current_ip`
IP=$IP".100"

#check if IP is taken using ping
count=`ping -c 1 $IP | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }'`

if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
        #change IP if available
        ifconfig $interface down
        ifconfig $interface $IP up
        ifconfig $interface
else
        #IP change not possible
        echo "IP not available"
fi
```

It should be fail safe provided in checks if the IP is taken or not in the network.

Don't forget that you need root privileges to run it.